# ¿Por qué no se reproduce mi animación css en 'Microsoft Edge'?

Tags: css, html5, animate.css, animacion-css, edge

Tengo una animación que se reproduce correctamente en todos los navegadores a excepción de 'Microsoft Edge' y después de intentarlo de varias maneras y repasar la documentación sobre como implementar animaciones no consigo que se vea correctamente. Este es mi código simplificado:

```css
  .div100 {position: absolute;width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto}
  .div25 {width: 22%; display: inline-block;}
  .div25 img {position: relative;top:-50px; left:25%; z-index: -9;}
  .div25.entrada1 img {animation: entrada1 1000s linear; animation-delay: 1s; opacity: 0;}
  .div25.entrada2 img {animation: entrada1 1000s linear; animation-delay: 2s; opacity: 0;}
  .div25.entrada3 img {animation: entrada1 1000s linear; animation-delay: 3s; opacity: 0;}
  .div25.entrada4 img {animation: entrada1 1000s linear; animation-delay: 4s; opacity: 0;}

  
  @keyframes entrada1 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}
  @-o-keyframes entrada1 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}
  @-moz-keyframes entrada1 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}
  @-webkit-keyframes entrada1 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}

  @keyframes entrada2 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}
  @-o-keyframes entrada2 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}
  @-moz-keyframes entrada2 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}
  @-webkit-keyframes entrada2 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}

  @keyframes entrada3 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}
  @-o-keyframes entrada3 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}
  @-moz-keyframes entrada3 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}
  @-webkit-keyframes entrada3 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}

  @keyframes entrada4 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}
  @-o-keyframes entrada4 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}
  @-moz-keyframes entrada4 {0%{o pacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}
  @-webkit-keyframes entrada4 {0%{opacity: 0;}0.0001%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="div100">
        <div class="div25 entrada1">
            <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x100" alt="">
        </div>
            <div class="div25 entrada2">
                    <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
                    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x100" alt="">
                </div>
        <div class="div25 entrada3">
            <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="div25 entrada4">
             <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
             <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x100" alt="">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Quizás estés teniendo un problema por la versión de Edge. ¿Cuál usas? En mi caso la **44.18362.449.0** y la animación se ejecuta correctamente.

Comment: Pues en principio está bien actualizado... pero voy a desinstalar y volver a probar. Gracias por el consejo.